# How to test a customized clean method in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have the following ModelForm

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_file = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def clean(self):
        form_file = self.cleaned_data['my_file']
        file_name = form_file.name
        if MyModel.objects.filter(my_file_name=file_name).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This file already exists")
```

Actually works but I need to add some unit tests to the customized clean method. Could you help me with that? Im using Django 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### use MultiValueDict to generate the file data

```
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict
from django.test import TestCase
from .forms import MyModelForm
from django.core.files import File
class MyModelFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_form_clean(self):
        file = File(open('/path/to/myfile', 'rb'))
        files = MultiValueDict({'my_file':[file]})
        form = MyModelForm(files=files)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        form.save()
        form_duplicated = MyModelForm(files=files)
        self.assertFalse(form_duplicated.is_valid())
```